Does $C\times \omega_\alpha$ admit a positive dimensional compactification?
Let $C$ be the Cantor set and $\alpha > 0$ a non-limit ordinal with $|C| = \mathfrak{c} < \aleph_\alpha$. Consider the space $C\times \omega_\alpha$.
By the exercise 9K in Gillman and Jerison, $\beta(C\times \omega_\alpha) = C\times (\omega_\alpha+1)$. If $Z$ is any compactification of $C\times \omega_\alpha$ then there exists a surjection $f:C\times (\omega_\alpha+1)\to Z$ such that $f(x, \gamma) = (x, \gamma)$ for $x\in C, \gamma < \omega_\alpha$ and $f(C\times \{\omega_\alpha\}) = Z\setminus (C\times \omega_\alpha)$.
Can it be so that $\dim Z > 0$ where $\dim$ is the Lebesgue covering dimension?
Context: I've shown that if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, $\dim X = 0$ and $|\beta X\setminus X| < \mathfrak{c}$ then $\dim Z = 0$ for every compactification $Z$ of $X$. I am wondering if this can be true if $|\beta X\setminus X| \geq \mathfrak{c}$.


Yes, under the above prerequisites, there exists always a compactification $Z$, which contains the unit interval $[0, 1]$:

It is well-known, that there exists a continuous, surjective map
$f: C \rightarrow [0,1]$
(for instance, Engelking, General topology, 4.5.9 (b)).
By the above referenced exercise from Gilman Jerison,
it is
$\beta(C \times \omega_\alpha) \setminus (C \times \omega_\alpha)
\cong  C $.
Hence, $[0, 1]$ is a continuous image of the remainder.
Of course, $C \times \omega_\alpha$ is locally compact.
Hence, by Engelking, 3.5.13, $C \times \omega_\alpha$ has a compactification $Z$, such that its remainder $Z \setminus (C \times \omega_\alpha)$
is homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$.
In particular, $\text{dim} Z > 0$.

I wasn't aware of this thorem, thank you
